# PHP utf8 variable encoding (HMAC Key -> C# Server)

Tags: c#, php, hash, utf-8

I'm trying to create a PHP client wrapper to talk to a .NET API. What I have is working but I am new to PHP development and what I have now looks like it may not work 100% of the time.

C# code I am trying to replicate:

```
private static void HMAC_Debug()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Secret Key (Base64): 'qCJ6KNCd/ASFOt1cL5uq2TUYcRjplpYUy7QdUmvaCTs='");
    var secret = Convert.FromBase64String("qCJ6KNCd/ASFOt1cL5uq2TUYcRjplpYUy7QdUmvaCTs=");

    Console.WriteLine("Value To Hash (UTF8): 'MyHashingValue©'");
    var value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyHashingValue©");

    using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(secret))
    {
        byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(value);
        string requestSignatureBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);

        Console.WriteLine("Resulting Hash (Base64): '{0}'", requestSignatureBase64String);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

My PHP Equiv:

```
    $rawKey = base64_decode("qCJ6KNCd/ASFOt1cL5uq2TUYcRjplpYUy7QdUmvaCTs=");

//        $hashValArr =  unpack("C*", utf8_encode("MyHashingValue©"));        
//        
//        $hashVal = call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("C*"), $hashValArr));

    $hashVal = "MyHashingValue©";

    $raw = hash_hmac("sha256", $hashVal, $rawKey, TRUE);
    $rawEnc = base64_encode($raw);

    echo $rawEnc;
```

These two snippets produce the same Base64 output, but I am relying on the string variables in PHP being default encoded to UTF8 - is this a correct assumption or is there something more stable I can do?

You can see from the commented out PHP lines I attempted to manually encode it to UTF8 then extract out the ASCII bytes for the PHP HMAC function but it didn't produce the same output as the c# code.

Thanks

Marlon

Comment: If you save the php file as UTF-8, then the string in the file is going to be utf-8.

Comment: I can't rely on that though, I need to encode external content which I am not in control of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of PHP are you using?

In general you cannot rely on the encoding being UTF-8. In fact it might be possible that you just stored the file as UTF-8 (I guess without BOM) but older PHP versions (as far as I know before PHP 7) are not capable to work natively with unicode, they just read it as ASCII / Extended ASCII.

That said, if you do not manipulate the string it is possible that your example works because you are just processing the bytes that are stored in the variable. And if this byte sequence happend to be a UTF-8 encoded string at the time you inserted it into your source code it stays that way.

If you get the string from an abritrary source you should make sure which encoding is used and consider the multibyte string processing functions of PHP, which can work with different encodings [1].

[1] https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: Just quickly tried `$hashVal = mb_convert_encoding("MyHashingValue©", "UTF-8");` but it gives a different result to the C#. The final string needs to be composed from part my strings and partly variables passed to my wrapper - so I can't guarantee what format those will be. (Using latest PHP5)

Comment: I guess PHP does not know that the original encoding was UTF-8. The documentation says, if not specified, the internal encoding is used, which is not UTF-8, so it assumes you are passing something different. If variable data is coming from an HTTP request you might check on the content-encoding of the request. Somehow it should always be possible to determine the right encoding of the input-data. For your source code constants you might store and decode from base 64 strings to avoid suprises.

Comment: Ok good call on the base64 encoding, I'll give a few things a go and see what happens. Thanks